# realm sync with community server

Tags: mongodb, flutter, nosql, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm trying to build an app that has chat in it using flutter and mongoDB, I found something interesting about mongoDB that it has Realm that stores messages locally and when there is an internet connection it sync the messages with the mongoDB database server, so now the question I want to ask is  **can the Realm sync with mongoDB community server (local server), or it only syncs with mongoDB Atlas?** 

If it only syncs with mongoDB Atlas I really need to use my own local server so,  **is there away to make Realm sync with the local server? or is there even a better database I can use to store messages locally and then sync with the local database server when there is internet connection ?** 

Thank you so much.

Comment: Just a heads up - asking "is there a better database" is asking for opinions and "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more is off topic for StackOverflow" and will likely get your question closed. So best to avoid asking for recommendations

Comment: Realm can be used locally on one device where the database is stored locally *or* Realm can be used with Realm Sync which automatically synchronizes the local database with Atlas. It's not clear why you need your own server but if you're looking for a Serverless Solution (meaning YOU don't have to manage the server) many databases sync with their own backend server. I suggest exploring Realm as maintaining your own server often times diverts your attention from writing code to messing around with the server.